# How do I add ".." between variables in a function?

Tags: python, function

So I made the following function:

```
def marble_stats(a):
big_box=a//48
small_box=(a-big_box*48)//8
excess=a-((big_box*48)+(small_box*8))
cash=26*big_box+4*small_box-excess*2
return big_box,small_box,excess,cash

final=marble_stats(503)
print(final)
```

When I execute I get: (0, 0, 7, -14)

But what I need is (0..0..7..-14) to be printed. I tried cnoverting the variables into strings and concatenating them with ".." but the commas don't seem to go away. How do I get around this?

Comment: "*I tried cnoverting the variables into strings and concatenating them with '..'*"...can you show us your attempt? What output did you get? That sounds like the correct approach.

Comment: Simple. `final = '..'.join(marble_stats(503))`

Comment: Ok this time it ended up working. I must have done something wrong the first time. Thanks for the reply though!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
def marble_stats(a):
    big_box=a//48
    small_box=(a-big_box*48)//8
    excess=a-((big_box*48)+(small_box*8))
    cash=26*big_box+4*small_box-excess*2
    return str(big_box)+'..'+str(small_box)+'..'+str(excess)+'..'+str(cash)

final=marble_stats(503)
print(final)
```

out: 10..2..7..254

Answer (score 1):

To give you an alternative, here is a more pythonic way of doing it in my opinion:

```
def marble_stats(a):
    big_box=a//48
    small_box=(a-big_box*48)//8
    excess=a-((big_box*48)+(small_box*8))
    cash=26*big_box+4*small_box-excess*2
    return_list = [big_box,small_box,excess,cash]
    return '..'.join(str(x) for x in return_list)

final=marble_stats(503)
print(final)
```

**Output**

```
10..2..7..254
```

Comment: Agreed, `str.join` is the correct solution here, not the [Schlemiel the Painter's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joel_Spolsky#Schlemiel_the_Painter.27s_algorithm) that is repeated string concatenation. Optionally, `'..'.join(map(str, return_list))` can be used for succinctness/speed, but use whichever feels more comfortable here, it's hardly performance critical.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Good point! thank you for the feedback. I'll let it like this for readability, but you're totally right performance wise.